# Use Cypher to create a constraint to prevent duplicate relationships between nodes

Tags: neo4j

I am programmatically submitting cypher statements to build a graph. I create two nodes and I submit a cypher statement to add a relationship between them. No problem. However sometimes the relationship is already there so I need a way to make sure it doesn't get added a second time. I am able to add constraints to prevent duplicate nodes but I cannot find the syntax to do that with relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Cypher MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#query-merge-relationships) command. I believe it'll do what you're looking for.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you.